# How to use this slider multiple times in one page jQuery Fix

Tags: jquery

I want to reuse this slider multiple times but currently, jQuery that makes it work it works  only for one so other sliders next and prev and dots doesn't work because they share the same id I don't want to repeat my self so a solution with jquery will be helpful

Tried .closest .find jQuery methods

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   function detect_active(){
      // get active
      var get_active = $("#dp-slider .dp_item:first-child").data("class");
      $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
      $("#dp-dots li[data-class="+ get_active +"]").addClass("active");
     }
     $("#dp-next").click(function(){
      var total = $(".dp_item").length;
      $("#dp-slider .dp_item:first-child").hide().appendTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
      $.each($('.dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
       $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
      });
      detect_active();

     });

     $("#dp-prev").click(function(){
      var total = $(".dp_item").length;
      $("#dp-slider .dp_item:last-child").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
      $.each($('.dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
       $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
      });

      detect_active();
     });

     $("#dp-dots li").click(function(){
      $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
      console.log(get_slide);
      $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + get_slide + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
      $.each($('.dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
       $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
      });
     });


     $("body").on("click", "#dp-slider .dp_item:not(:first-child)", function(){
      var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
      console.log(get_slide);
      $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + get_slide + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
      $.each($('.dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
       $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
      });

      detect_active();
     });
    });
```

```css
  *{
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
  .dp-wrap {
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      perspective: 1000px;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .dp-slider {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .dp-slider div {
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .dp_item {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      color: #FFF;
      border-radius: 10px;
      transition: transform 1.2s;
  }
  .dp-img img {
      border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  #dp-slider .dp_item:first-child {
      z-index: 10 !important;
      transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px) !important;
  }
  .dp_item[data-position="2"] {
      z-index: 9;
      transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(10%) scale(0.9);
  }
  .dp_item[data-position="3"] {
      z-index: 8;
      transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(20%) scale(0.8);
  }
  .dp_item[data-position="4"] {
      z-index: 7;
      transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(30%) scale(0.7);
  }
  #dp-next,
  #dp-prev {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 16%;
      height: 33px;
      width: 33px;
      z-index: 10;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  #dp-prev {
      left: 15px;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  #dp-dots {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 25px;
      z-index: 12;
      left: 38%;
      cursor: default;
  }

  #dp-dots li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 13px;
      background: #ffff;
      border-radius: 50%;
  }
  #dp-dots li:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   background: #FA8C8C;
   transition: background .3s;
  }
  #dp-dots li.active {
      background: #FA8C8C;
  }
  .dp_item {
      width: 85%;
  }
  .dp-content ,
  .dp-img {
      text-align: left;
  }
  .dp_item {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-top: 5px solid #FA8C8C;
  }
  .dp-content {
      padding-left: 100px;
      padding-right: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .dp-content h2 {
      color: #41414B;
      font-family: Circular Std Bold;
      font-size: 48px;
      max-width: 460px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .dp-content p {
      color: #74747F;
      max-width: 490px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      font-size: 24px;
  }
  .dp-content .site-btn {
     margin-top: 15px;
     font-size: 13px;
     padding: 19px 40px;
  }
  .dp-img:before {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
      background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
      background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 25%;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      pointer-events: none;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75));
      background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75));
      background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255));
  }
  .dp-img img {
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: right;
  }
  #dp-slider,
  .dp-img img {
      height: 738px;
  }
  #dp-slider .dp_item:hover:not(:first-child) {
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  .site-btn {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Circular Std Medium";
    background: #FA8282;
    padding: 14px 43px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    top: -12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .site-btn:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
  }
  h1 { margin: 150px auto 30px auto; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="max-width: 1400px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="slider">
  <div class="dp-wrap">
    <div id="dp-slider">

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="1" data-position="1">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 1</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 1 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/739/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="2" data-position="2">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 2</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 2 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/738/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="3" data-position="3">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 3</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 3 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/737/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="4" data-position="4">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 4</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 4 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/736/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span id="dp-next">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>

    <span id="dp-prev">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>



    <ul id="dp-dots">
      <li data-class="1" class="active"></li>
      <li data-class="2"></li>
      <li data-class="3"></li>
      <li data-class="4"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
   <div class="container" style="max-width: 1400px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="slider">
  <div class="dp-wrap">
    <div id="dp-slider">

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="1" data-position="1">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 1</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 1 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/739/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="2" data-position="2">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 2</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 2 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/738/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="3" data-position="3">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 3</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 3 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/737/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="4" data-position="4">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 4</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 4 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/736/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span id="dp-next">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>

    <span id="dp-prev">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>



    <ul id="dp-dots">
      <li data-class="1" class="active"></li>
      <li data-class="2"></li>
      <li data-class="3"></li>
      <li data-class="4"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
   <div class="container" style="max-width: 1400px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="slider">
  <div class="dp-wrap">
    <div id="dp-slider">

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="1" data-position="1">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 1</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 1 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/739/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="2" data-position="2">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 2</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 2 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/738/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="3" data-position="3">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 3</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 3 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/737/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="4" data-position="4">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 4</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 4 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/736/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span id="dp-next">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>

    <span id="dp-prev">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>



    <ul id="dp-dots">
      <li data-class="1" class="active"></li>
      <li data-class="2"></li>
      <li data-class="3"></li>
      <li data-class="4"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Each slider should be independent

Comment: IDs [need to be unique](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute). If an element is accessed by its ID (e.g. when using `$('#dp-next')`) the result is expected to be a single element. Give the elements proper unique IDs and change your code to access the elements by class names: `$(".dp-prev")` for the changed element `<span class="dp-next">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced some IDs with Class. ID should not be duplicated on the same document. dp-slider ID will be duplicating. I have recode JS. I hope it's working fine now.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   function detect_active($ele){
      // get active
      var get_active = $ele.siblings("#dp-slider").find('.dp_item:first-child').data("class");
      $ele.siblings(".dp-dots").find('li').removeClass("active");
      $ele.siblings(".dp-dots").find("li[data-class="+ get_active +"]").addClass("active");
     }
     $(".dp-next").click(function(){
      var total = $(this).siblings('#dp-slider').find(".dp_item").length;
      var firstSlide = $(this).siblings("#dp-slider").find('.dp_item:first-child');
      firstSlide.hide();
      $(this).siblings("#dp-slider").append(firstSlide);
      $(this).siblings("#dp-slider").find('.dp_item:last-child').fadeIn();
      $(this).siblings('#dp-slider').find(".dp_item").each(function(index, dp_item) {
       $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
      });

      detect_active($(this));

     });

     $(".dp-prev").click(function(){
      var total = $(this).siblings('#dp-slider').find(".dp_item").length;
      var lastSlide = $(this).siblings("#dp-slider").find('.dp_item:last-child');
      lastSlide.hide();
      $(this).siblings("#dp-slider").prepend(lastSlide);
      $(this).siblings("#dp-slider").find('.dp_item:first-child').fadeIn();

      $(this).siblings('#dp-slider').find(".dp_item").each(function(index, dp_item) {
       $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
      });

      detect_active($(this));
     });

     $(".dp-dots li").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings("li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
      var targetSlide = $(this).parents('.dp-dots').siblings('#dp-slider').find(".dp_item[data-class=" + get_slide + "]");
      targetSlide.hide();
      $(this).parents('.dp-dots').siblings('#dp-slider').prepend(targetSlide);
      $(this).parents('.dp-dots').siblings('#dp-slider').find('.dp_item:first-child').fadeIn();

      $(this).parents('.dp-dots').siblings('#dp-slider').find(".dp_item").each(function(index, dp_item) {
       $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
      });
     });


     $("body").on("click", "#dp-slider .dp_item:not(:first-child)", function(){
      var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
      var clickedSlide = $(this).parents("#dp-slider").find(".dp_item[data-class=" + get_slide + "]");
      clickedSlide.hide();
      $(this).parents("#dp-slider").prepend(clickedSlide);
      $(this).parents("#dp-slider").find('.dp_item:first-child').fadeIn();
      $(this).parents("#dp-slider").find(".dp_item").each(function(index, dp_item) {
       $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
      });
      // $.each($('.dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
      //  $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
      // });

      detect_active($(this).parents("#dp-slider").siblings('.dp-next'));
     });
    });
```

```css
*{
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
  .dp-wrap {
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      perspective: 1000px;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .dp-slider {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .dp-slider div {
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .dp_item {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      color: #FFF;
      border-radius: 10px;
      transition: transform 1.2s;
  }
  .dp-img img {
      border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  #dp-slider .dp_item:first-child {
      z-index: 10 !important;
      transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px) !important;
  }
  .dp_item[data-position="2"] {
      z-index: 9;
      transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(10%) scale(0.9);
  }
  .dp_item[data-position="3"] {
      z-index: 8;
      transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(20%) scale(0.8);
  }
  .dp_item[data-position="4"] {
      z-index: 7;
      transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(30%) scale(0.7);
  }
  .dp-next,
  .dp-prev {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 16%;
      height: 33px;
      width: 33px;
      z-index: 10;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dp-prev {
      left: 15px;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  .dp-dots {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 25px;
      z-index: 12;
      left: 38%;
      cursor: default;
  }

  .dp-dots li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 13px;
      background: #ffff;
      border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .dp-dots li:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   background: #FA8C8C;
   transition: background .3s;
  }
  .dp-dots li.active {
      background: #FA8C8C;
  }
  .dp_item {
      width: 85%;
  }
  .dp-content ,
  .dp-img {
      text-align: left;
  }
  .dp_item {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-top: 5px solid #FA8C8C;
  }
  .dp-content {
      padding-left: 100px;
      padding-right: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .dp-content h2 {
      color: #41414B;
      font-family: Circular Std Bold;
      font-size: 48px;
      max-width: 460px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .dp-content p {
      color: #74747F;
      max-width: 490px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      font-size: 24px;
  }
  .dp-content .site-btn {
     margin-top: 15px;
     font-size: 13px;
     padding: 19px 40px;
  }
  .dp-img:before {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
      background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
      background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 25%;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      pointer-events: none;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75));
      background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75));
      background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255));
  }
  .dp-img img {
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: right;
  }
  #dp-slider,
  .dp-img img {
      height: 738px;
  }
  #dp-slider .dp_item:hover:not(:first-child) {
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  .site-btn {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Circular Std Medium";
    background: #FA8282;
    padding: 14px 43px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    top: -12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .site-btn:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
  }
  h1 { margin: 150px auto 30px auto; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="max-width: 1400px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="slider">
  <div class="dp-wrap">
    <div id="dp-slider">

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="1" data-position="1">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 1</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 1 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/739/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="2" data-position="2">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 2</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 2 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/738/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="3" data-position="3">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 3</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 3 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/737/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="4" data-position="4">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 4</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 4 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/736/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span class="dp-next">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>

    <span class="dp-prev">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>



    <ul class="dp-dots">
      <li data-class="1" class="active"></li>
      <li data-class="2"></li>
      <li data-class="3"></li>
      <li data-class="4"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
   <div class="container" style="max-width: 1400px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="slider">
  <div class="dp-wrap">
    <div id="dp-slider">

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="1" data-position="1">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 1</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 1 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/739/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="2" data-position="2">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 2</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 2 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/738/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="3" data-position="3">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 3</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 3 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/737/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="4" data-position="4">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 4</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 4 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/736/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span class="dp-next">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>

    <span class="dp-prev">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>



    <ul class="dp-dots">
      <li data-class="1" class="active"></li>
      <li data-class="2"></li>
      <li data-class="3"></li>
      <li data-class="4"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
   <div class="container" style="max-width: 1400px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="slider">
  <div class="dp-wrap">
    <div id="dp-slider">

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="1" data-position="1">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 1</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 1 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/739/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="2" data-position="2">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 2</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 2 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/738/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="3" data-position="3">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 3</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 3 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/737/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dp_item" data-class="4" data-position="4">
        <div class="dp-content">

          <h2>Slide 4</h2>
          <p> This is Slide 4 </p>
          <a href="#" class="site-btn">Read More…</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dp-img">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/821/736/any" alt="investing">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span class="dp-next">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>

    <span class="dp-prev">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51.401 51.401">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #fa8c8c;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
              stroke-width: 7px;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path id="Rectangle_4_Copy" data-name="Rectangle 4 Copy" class="cls-1" d="M32.246,0V33.178L0,31.953" transform="translate(0.094 25.276) rotate(-45)"/>
      </svg>
    </span>



    <ul class="dp-dots">
      <li data-class="1" class="active"></li>
      <li data-class="2"></li>
      <li data-class="3"></li>
      <li data-class="4"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
```